# Paperclip retrieve styles dimentions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I work with **Rails 4** and use **PaperClip** to attach images to different models.

I would like to retrieve styles dimensions in order to use them as a hint for user, something like:

```
<%= t('image_dimensions_hint', :dimensions => Person.avatar.standard') %>
```

When my model `Person` looks like that:

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
 :styles => { 
   :standard => "150x150>",
   :small => "50x50>>",
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the question but I think you can get the dimensions with this:

```
:dimensions => Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(file.queued_for_write[:original].path)
```

Comment: I need to get the style dimensions per model, even without having an existing file uploaded, neither an object of this model. Assume I have different models (Person, Book, etc...) with different attachment definitions.